# How do I control the output folders for C# projects in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio (currently working in VS 2019), there is a rich collection of build macros that I can use in C++ projects that let me control which folder compiled files are stored in depending on the configuration chosen.  So, I can have separate configurations for each customer.  By default, the output folder is given by $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration).  So, my CAPS project can have output for the Release Algoma project stored in CAPS/Release Algoma, and a build for US Steel can have its files stored in CAPS/Release US Steel.  When I add a customer configuration, I don't have to change anything, and my files are automatically stored where I want them.

In C#, I don't have those build macros.  If I add a new configuration to my solution, I have to go into every project in my solution and change the output folder.  Do I have those build macros available for C# projects, or is there some other way to control the output folder based on configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Your output directory can be specified in the project file or other MSBuild targets file by setting the `$(OutputPath)` variable.

You can do this conditionally:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(SomeCondition)'=='foo'>
  <OutputPath>foo\whatever\...</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- or set the condition on the property -->
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath Condition="'$(SomeCondition)'=='foo'>foo\whatever\...</OutputPath>
  <OutputPath Condition="'$(SomeCondition)'==''>default\whatever\...</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or in many cases by just building the value directly using other variables

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\$(Configuration)\$(MSBuildProjectName)</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that `$(SolutionDir)` is only defined when building in the IDE (according to the documentation), so another approach might be to put a Directory.Build.props in your solution folder or repo root to define the base path for your output directory (you can use `$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)` to refer to the directory in which the file is located).  You can also define the `$(OutputPath)` in that file, and it will be inherited by any other project (hence the use of `$(MSBuildProjectName)` in the example) - unless those projects set the value themselves, overriding your default.

Answer (score 1):

> In C# ... If I add a new configuration to my solution, I have to go into every project in my solution and change the output folder.

If you use the newer SDK-style `.csproj` project files, then the output folder will be constructed automatically, taking into account configuration, platform and target framework as necessary. Can you upgrade your `.csproj` files?

---

Here's a snippet from a "legacy" (non-SDK-style) `.csproj` file:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- snip -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <!-- snip -->
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <!-- snip -->
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- snip -->
</Project>
```

Notice how it explicitly lists the `OutputPath` for each configuration? When you add a new solution configuration, that configuration must be added in every `.csproj` file manually.

With SDK-style projects, the equivalent `.csproj` file looks like:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The `Sdk` attribute brings in a bunch of MSBuild props/targets from the SDK which compute the `OutputPath` for you, based upon the `Configurations`, `Platforms` and `TargetFrameworks` properties relevant to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? In project properties, Build Events, Edit Post-Build, then this command should do it:

`xcopy "$(TargetDir)" "$(TargetDir)$(ConfigurationName)\" /Y /I`

You may need to adapt to your exact needs, filter files, etc.

[image]

Comment: It would be better to configure your project to build directly into the place you want it to. Using a post-build event like this will make your build slower.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Could you please provide an explanation about how to do that in VS in your answer (ex. is it linked to the .NET framework version you're targetting)?

Comment: I've extended my answer. You can also override the output path via the `OutputPath` property explicitly in your `.csproj` file if you want different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Directory.Build.props is powerful for this.

<OutputPath> can be set in a Directory.Build.props file.

You may find that you must delete one or more <OutputPath> values that are already in the csproj file in order for the <OutputPath> value(s) in Directory.Build.props to take effect. This is because, generally, the <OutputPath> values in the project file will override those in Directory.Build.props. The $(Configuration) variable may be used as part of an <OutputPath> in a Directory.Build.props file.

You may also set a value in Directory.Build.props e.g. <OutputDirExample> and then use that in the <OutputPath> values in your csproj file e.g.

```
...
...
<OutputPath>$(OutputDirExample)\Debug\</OutputPath>
...
...
<OutputPath>$(OutputDirExample)\Release\</OutputPath>
...
...
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022

**Important:** When experimenting with a Directory.Build.props file, close and reopen the solution (.sln) after any changes to a Directory.Build.props file to ensure that the udpated Directory.Build.props file takes effect (forgetting to do this, can cause hours of confusion).